# Trouble finding the performance issue in my unity game

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, rendering

Hey I am having some issues finding my performance bottleneck in my Unity Game. I have looked here is a screencap of the profiler :

[image]

[image]

[image]

It looks as if this is just normal rendering but is there something I am doing that is really bogging the perf down ?

Comment: I can give very general advice like not putting excessively large loops in Update; don't use GameObject.GetComponent or GameObject.Find in Update; if you only use a class for storing data and not for containing methods use a strict to avoid garbage collector allocations. But I can't tell you what's wrong with your project without seeing all of your code. You need to learn what can be problem areas and go looking for instances of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also open overview panel of profiler where you can get a detailed breakdown.

Here is unity tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBpXiJ9G3OY